# Discord.js GuildMember.hasPermission?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make a warn command for my discord bot but the system I made for non admins to not be able to use it doesn't really work because of the `msg.guildmember.haspermission` thing. I'm not sure what's going wrong can anyone help me out here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `member` instead of `GuildMember` at lines 6 and 7 in the screenshot.

I'd also suggest checking out Discord's [official API documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference) and the discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member): `msg` doesn't have a `GuildMember` property it has a `member` so the line should be `!msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')`

PS: you are not using the `role` variable in your screenshot.

Comment: Okay testing it out now.